# What should this question be tagged with?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently saw this question: [Good Ways to Get Over that Vim Learning Curve?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9209/good-ways-to-get-over-that-vim-learning-curve), and I saw that it was tagged with [vim-windows](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-windows) and [macvim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macvim). Both of these tags are completely wrong for the question, and I was going to edit it, but I can't for the life of me figure out what tags we have that are appropriate for the question.

I think perhaps we should make a tag for *"philosophical"* questions about vim, e.g. general questions about how to effectively use vim that aren't about any particular topic inside of vim. I can see a tag like that appropriate for questions like this one, or even [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8313/philosophical-question-is-remapping-keys-to-allow-navigation-in-insert-mode-bad), which to be fair is closed as primarily opinion based.

I imagine there are at least 10-20 questions like this, although I didn't really look for them super hard.

So basically my question is, *should* we have a tag like this, and *what* should the tag be?

Comment: Since it has macvim, I guess the vim-windows tag is a misuse, and meant to be the MS Windows one. I removed that. If anything, I guess it should be tagged vim-tutor. :P

Answer (score 2):

If this would be Stack Overflow, I would close that question as "primarily opinion based" (or possibly "too broad") without much thought.

But this isn't Stack Overflow and I think we can perhaps permit ourselves some more leeway; Stack Overflow has about four times more questions in a *single day* than we get a in a *year*. But it seems to me that we need to first think and discus the scope of the site when it comes to opinionated and/or broad-ish questions. Do we want to allow this at all, and if so, under which conditions? And which questions would be eligible?

I believe some other Stack Exchange sites have done this successfully, but let's do it *right* rather than half-arsed. I would most certainly *not* be in favour of just allowing all opinion-based questions − it's just not what the Stack Exchange platform does and provides the tools to do.

Unfortunately I don't have time right now and fully think about and address the issue, and I'll be at the Golang UK conference and a small holiday in the next few days (I'll be back on Monday), but I encourage everyone to think about it and put forth arguments either way.

In the meantime, I've closed this question. We can always re-open it later.